# Getting window restored bounds

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

When you maximize a window in Macos, the window fills the screen.

What I want to be able to do is get the windows restored position and size, like when you press the maximize button again to restore the original position. How can you do this?

I need this for saving the window position on exit.

Comment: Use a notification (`NSWindow.willEnterFullScreenNotification`) to get the window size before it goes to the full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method prepared for this task in `NSWindow`.

You could ask your ViewController for its NSWindow and set an AutosaveName for its Frame like..

```
[self.view.window setFrameAutosaveName:@"VerySpecialWindowAutoSaveName"];
```

which will end up in `NSUserDefaults` of your App as entry like...

```
"NSWindow Frame VerySpecialWindowAutoSaveName" = "300 100 1200 1005 0 0 2560 1289"
```

But the best place for this code is ... there is no best place because it depends on your apps approach.

The whole process can be challenging when you have multiple windows in a document based application but as you can set the AutosaveName per documents window you are able to recover the frame if needed, at least for the last document. Should be mentioned that you can set the AutosaveName in InterfaceBuilder and in Code as well - so keep an eye on it they follow the same name if you use both IB & code for one and the same window.

and an example in swift you can find [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/krzyzanowskim/a16567e897455dd4471b27b78165d581)